# How to set scope correctly for a parameterized fixture

Tags: python, pytest

Scope of a parameterized fixture is not working.

Here is an example of the fixture and the test:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def my_fixture(request):
       # make some API calls
       # print API call response
       return response
```

Tests

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('my_fixture',['a','b']):
def test_scenario_1(my_fixture):
      assert response['text'] == 'abc' 

@pytest.mark.parametrize('my_fixture',['a','b']):
def test_scenario_2(my_fixture):
      assert response['image'] == 'def'
```

When I run the tests I see the API responses printed 4 times(twice for a parameter and twice for b parameter). I was expecting it to be printed just twice(once for both the parameters - a and b) since both the tests use same set of parameters and the fixed is scoped session. Obviously, if I don't parameterize the fixture the api response is printed once. Pytest version is 7.4.2

Comment: Your code is full of troubles: comments are C++ style, not Python, assert lines do not work. Please clean up and post code that work before we can help. We cannot guess your intention by looking at this code.

Comment: Cleaned up a bit to make it more clear/clean. Thanks for taking a look at this.

Comment: `my_fixture` is as parametrize is duplicated with the fixture. Also, what do 'a' and 'b' has to do with the tests?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you want to pass parameters 'a', then 'b' to the fixture `my_fixture`. Here is how I would do it:

```py
import pytest


@pytest.fixture(scope="session", params=["a", "b"])
def my_fixture(request):
    param = request.param  # param='a', then 'b'

    # Call the API and return the response
    return {
        "param": param,
        "text": "abc",
        "image": "def",
    }


def test_scenario_1(my_fixture):
    assert my_fixture["text"] == "abc"


def test_scenario_2(my_fixture):
    assert my_fixture["image"] == "def"
```

Output:

```
test_foo.py::test_scenario_1[a] PASSED
test_foo.py::test_scenario_2[a] PASSED
test_foo.py::test_scenario_1[b] PASSED
test_foo.py::test_scenario_2[b] PASSED
```

Note that pytest groups tests by parameters, not by test names.

Comment: I think even with this approach, the fixture is called multiple times even though it is scoped to session.

Comment: Definitely. It is called once for each parameter 'a', and 'b'. If you only want to call exactly once, you will have to redesign your tests. I cannot help you there because I don't want to guess.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are misunderstanding how those test fixtures are implemented.

> Function (Set up and torn down once for each test function).
>
> Class (Setup and torn down once for each test class).
>
> Module (Set up and torn down once for each test module/file).
>
> Session (Set up and torn down once for each test session i.e comprising one or more test files)

This gives a description from the docs on how each scope is handled.  As you can see with `Session` it is called twice (once on build-up and once on tear-down for each test).